# SQLite in Javascript: Too much data in memory

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, leaflet, web-worker

I have an HTML5 application that incorporates a few SQLite APIs to create an application that can:

- Read a sqlite database on a clients computer (based on user input) and load the contents to memory.
- Asynchronously load image blobs from the database to build a disconnected mapviewer using Leaflet.js / Openlayers.js
- Load N number of these sqlite databases in one session as layers within leaflet, where N is the maximum number of database that the client computer can handle in memory before crashing

This creates a nice clean app that can run on newer phone/tablet/PC browsers and open/view content without installing anything.  My application does this by using a javascript library that I suspect was meant for node.js use.

My problem:

- Map data in sqlite form can be big (over 2GBs easily).  My application handles small sqlite db's fine but if a single sqlite db is opened over a certain GB limit (> 2.5GB, let's say), the browser crashes.
- This library loads my sqlite databases to memory as a javascript object
- Due to the limitations of client-side cache storage, I can't "replicate" the DB via IndexedDB because there isnt enough cache space especially on mobile devices

Is there an existing sqlite javascript library that will NOT load the entire DB to memory?  Is there a way to thread or spawn multiple processes via web-workers so I don't overload the browser process with this memory burden?  This type of map data (tiles) is such that I only need between 8-12 rows from the DB at any given time.

Basically the only real answer I can think of is simply making the databases such that they do not exceed this memory threshold and limiting the total number of databases that can be loaded.  I would like to see if there are any other options I am overlooking.

TL-DR;  I am making gigabyte-sized objects in javascript and the browser is crashing as a result.  How can I make it not do so?

Answer (score 0):

No matter what mechanism you choose for storing local data, you will be limited by cache sizes that range from 5-100Mb which is an order of magnitude smaller than you want.  What you can do is have the user upload their data to a server (your server) and query against that server using   http service calls.  There are a few implementations of cache servers that can speed results but I believe that you are exceding the limits of what can be done in a browser sandbox.

Comment: Yes the server-side solution is a good one however the functionality here needs to stay disconnected from any and all networks.  Think of a person in a disaster area with no connectivity but they still need a map on a laptop/mobile device to work.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  I think that the devices are simply not going to be sufficient to carry that kind of data.  Having dealt with maps as an issue (personally),  I ended up using Garmin maps that come on a stick.  It was not a great solution but it managed my rather limited needs.